# How did gdprscript.js get into the header of my Weebly site?

Tags: html, templates, weebly

When I view the source of my website, I am seeing this script inserted into my website.  However I cannot find the template where it is being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This javascript html tag is inserted **automatically** by Weebly's backend server itself.  It inserts it immediatly after the `<head>` element and before any items you have defined in your actual template file.

```html
<script src="/gdpr/gdprscript.js?buildTime=1558379751&hasRemindMe=true&stealth=false"></script>
```

### What does it do?

This code forces the display of the "This site uses cookies..." message that pops over the bottom part of the page.  It also handles the user's selection.

### Why is it inserted if my site does not use cookies?

It is inserted because Weebly *itself* forces your site to use cookies.  It does this to enable its own collection of analytics on your homepage.

### Does it slow down my site

Yes.  Code like this should be inserted after the site content.

### Can it be removed?

You [may be able have this removed by contacting Weebly](https://community.weebly.com/t5/App-Center/Weebly-GDPR-Compulsory-Cookie-Notification-Popup-Alert-Can-It-Be/td-p/126881) directly.